# How to change product image size on category product view for a specific product only?

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-view

I am trying to change the image size for a specific product only without affecting other products, how do I achieve this?

Comment: It depends, how would you target the product? Will it be only in the frontend? Could you add a class to the container of the product? If so you could use css to affect an image of a product with a certain class

Comment: The right fix is to manipulate the dimensions in the `etc/view.xml` file but that would affect all the product images in the site. I am thinking if that is possible to use that fix to just one product.

Comment: Well, you could add a new image type for the product and fill it for desired products, check this: https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/set-custom-image-role-for-product-in-magento-2-507